# How to modify a C int array allocated in C code, from an embeded python script?

Tags: c++, python, arrays, embed

I'm trying to embed python in a C++ application.
The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to modify a C array (int) from python.

I load my python script using the standard PyImport_Import and Co. functions.

Is it possible to pass the address of my array like that :

```
//build one argument that we will modify INSIDE python
int iMyArg[5];
//pass the address as py arg
PyObject* argsTuple = Py_BuildValue("(l)", iMyArg);
PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, argsTuple);
```

And then modify my array size (of fixed lenght, here, 5) from python in some way ?
I tried reading what ctypes offer, but I can't get any success. I tried to look if there is any way to write to memory using python, I don't see how.

Note: returning this array from python is not an option, as I believe being able to modify this iMyArg array directly from python would be much faster. It's a simple example, but I'm trying to use arrays that may be very large (for OHCL data).

Thanks !